# Group by date intervall Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I want to retrieve sum of weight data from a table over a whole month.
what I need help with is that I want to group the result into 2 parts
sum of 1-15 of the month
and second line 16-31 of the month.

```
SELECT(SUM(B.SCALE_WEIGHT) FROM TRACKING.DATALOG_TAB B WHERE B.MATERIALID= 1 AND B.SCALE_EVENTDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(TRUNC(TO_DATE('2020-10-1', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MONTH')) AND TO_DATE(TRUNC(TO_DATE('2020-10-1', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MONTH')+30)
GROUP BY(somthing like this - 1-15  and 16-31)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
select
    1 + floor(extract(day from scale_eventdate) / 16) as fortnight,
    sum(b.scale_weight) as sum_scale_weight
from tracking.datalog_tab b 
where 
    materialid = 1 
    and scale_eventdate >= date '2020-10-01'
    and scale_eventdate <  date '2020-11-01'
group by 1 + floor(extract(day from scale_eventdate) / 16)
```

This extracts the day number from the date, and then use artithmetics: every day from the 1 to to the 15th of the month included goes to `fortnight` number `1`, and everything afterwards goes to bucket `2`.

We could also do this with `to_char()` and a `case` expression, which is somewhat more expressive:

```
select
    case when to_char(scale_eventdate, 'dd') <= '15' then 1 else 2 end as fortnight,
    sum(b.scale_weight) as sum_scale_weight
from tracking.datalog_tab b 
where 
    materialid = 1 
    and scale_eventdate >= date '2020-10-01'
    and scale_eventdate <  date '2020-11-01'
group by case when to_char(scale_eventdate, 'dd') <= '15' then 1 else 2 end
```

Note that I changed the date filtering logic to use standard date literals, which makes the query shorter and more readable.

Comment: That was correct, But i want to select multible columns ? 
 another column fo materialId = 2

Comment: @B.j: this is a different question really. If so, you should ask a *new question*. This answers the question that you have asked.

Comment: Posted a new one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64820490/retrieve-multible-columns-group-by-date-intervall