# retrieve multible columns group by date intervall

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to retrieve multible columns, sum of weight data from a table over a whole month. what I need help with is that I want to group the result into 2 parts sum of 1-15 of the month and second line 16-31 of the month.

```
Select TO_CHAR(sysdate) dummy

(SELECT(SUM(B.SCALE_WEIGHT) FROM TRACKING.DATALOG_TAB B WHERE B.MATERIALID= 1 
AND B.SCALE_EVENTDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(TRUNC(TO_DATE('2020-10-1', 'YYYY-MM- 
DD'),'MONTH')) AND TO_DATE(TRUNC(TO_DATE('2020-11-1', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
'MONTH')+16))  as MTRL1,


(SELECT(SUM(B.SCALE_WEIGHT) FROM TRACKING.DATALOG_TAB B WHERE B.MATERIALID= 2 
AND B.SCALE_EVENTDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(TRUNC(TO_DATE('2020-10-1', 'YYYY-MM- 
DD'),'MONTH')) AND TO_DATE(TRUNC(TO_DATE('2020-11-1', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
'MONTH')+16)) as MTRL2


FROM DUAL
GROUP BY(somthing like this - 1-15  and 16-31);
```

UPDATE

the result should look like this
[image: enter code here]

Comment: Your both queries are the same except B.MATERIALID. and your dates are in different months. Can you please share what is the exact requirement?

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like this:

```
select 
  sum(case when b.materialid = 1 and
                to_number(to_char(b.scale_eventdate, 'dd')) between  1 and 15 then 
                b.scale_weight 
      end) mtrl1,
  --      
  sum(case when b.materialid = 2 and
                to_number(to_char(b.scale_eventdate, 'dd')) between 16 and 31 then 
                b.scale_weight 
      end) mtrl2
from datalog_tab b
where to_char(b.scale_eventdate, 'yyyymm') = '202010'
```

In other words, check whether day of `scale_eventdate` column belongs to 1st or 2nd half of the month and sum `scale_weight` accordingly.

Comment: it's mutlible MtrlID.  it's not just 1.  i want to select for Id 1 aond Id 2

Comment: Aha, didn't see it. Include MATERIALID into CASE. I modififed code I wrote, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tracking.datalog_tab ( materialid, scale_eventdate, scale_weight ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-10-01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-10-15', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-10-16', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-10-31', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-10-01', -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-10-15', -2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-10-16', -3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-10-31', -4 FROM DUAL;
```

You can use:

```sql
SELECT MATERIALID,
       CASE
       WHEN EXTRACT( DAY FROM SCALE_EVENTDATE ) <= 15
       THEN ' 1-15'
       ELSE '16-31'
       END AS day_range,
       SUM(SCALE_WEIGHT)
FROM   TRACKING.DATALOG_TAB
WHERE  MATERIALID IN ( 1, 2 ) 
AND    SCALE_EVENTDATE >= DATE '2020-10-01'
AND    SCALE_EVENTDATE <  DATE '2020-11-01'
GROUP BY
       MATERIALID,
       CASE
       WHEN EXTRACT( DAY FROM SCALE_EVENTDATE ) <= 15
       THEN ' 1-15'
       ELSE '16-31'
       END;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> MATERIALID | DAY_RANGE | SUM(SCALE_WEIGHT)
> ---------: | :-------- | ----------------:
>          1 |  1-15     |                 3
>          2 |  1-15     |                -3
>          1 | 16-31     |                 7
>          2 | 16-31     |                -7
> ```

Or, if you want them as columns then `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT MATERIALID,
         CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT( DAY FROM SCALE_EVENTDATE ) <= 15
         THEN ' 1-15'
         ELSE '16-31'
         END AS day_range,
         SCALE_WEIGHT
  FROM   TRACKING.DATALOG_TAB
  WHERE  MATERIALID IN ( 1, 2 ) 
  AND    SCALE_EVENTDATE >= DATE '2020-10-01'
  AND    SCALE_EVENTDATE <  DATE '2020-11-01'
)
PIVOT (
  SUM( scale_weight ) FOR ( materialid, day_range ) IN (
    ( 1, ' 1-15' ) AS mtrl1_01_15,
    ( 1, '16-31' ) AS mtrl1_16_31,
    ( 2, ' 1-15' ) AS mtrl2_01_15,
    ( 2, '16-31' ) AS mtrl2_16_31
  )
);
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> MTRL1_01_15 | MTRL1_16_31 | MTRL2_01_15 | MTRL2_16_31
> ----------: | ----------: | ----------: | ----------:
>           3 |           7 |          -3 |          -7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=804fabb60a342bdef39bb3a74c6dcbc8)*

---

## Update

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT MATERIALID,
         CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT( DAY FROM SCALE_EVENTDATE ) <= 15
         THEN ' 1-15 '
         ELSE '16-31 '
         END
         || TO_CHAR( scale_eventdate, 'Mon' ) AS date_range,
         SCALE_WEIGHT
  FROM   /*TRACKING.*/DATALOG_TAB
  WHERE  MATERIALID IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) 
  AND    SCALE_EVENTDATE >= DATE '2020-10-01'
  AND    SCALE_EVENTDATE <  DATE '2020-11-01'
)
PIVOT (
  SUM( scale_weight ) FOR materialid IN (
    1 AS sum_mtrl1_weight,
    2 AS sum_mtrl2_weight,
    3 AS sum_mtrl3_weight
  )
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE /*TRACKING.*/datalog_tab ( materialid, scale_eventdate, scale_weight ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-10-01',  25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-10-15',  75 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-10-16', 125 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-10-31', 375 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-10-01',  90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-10-15', 110 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-10-16',  90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-10-31', 125 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2020-10-01', 120 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2020-10-16', 120 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2020-10-31', 240 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> DATE_RANGE | SUM_MTRL1_WEIGHT | SUM_MTRL2_WEIGHT | SUM_MTRL3_WEIGHT
> :--------- | ---------------: | ---------------: | ---------------:
>  1-15 Oct  |              100 |              200 |              120
> 16-31 Oct  |              500 |              215 |              360
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3841db67bd3a803d32e066ff1939a676)*

Comment: @MTO i have updated the quastion, se how the table should look like